# How to convert an Observable<String> to JSON

Tags: java, json, object, rx-java

I want to convert an Observable object into a json object

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Observable<String> response = accountSearchService.searchAccount(paramMap, "", 0, 1);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    AccountSearchResult resultDto = mapper.convertValue(response.subscribe().toString(), AccountSearchResult.class);
```

This is what I'm trying to do but getting OnErrorNotImplementedException.
Please someone help me on this.

Comment: What is throwing the exception? Since you aren't actually using an `Observable`, can you provide a minimum amount of code the exhibits the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subscribe()` method doesn't return the actual value of the subscription, it just triggers a subscription to that observable. Instead, you have to "listen" to the subscription and do your operation once it's done. Something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Observable<String> response = accountSearchService.searchAccount(paramMap, "", 0, 1);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    response.subscribe(stringValue -> {
            AccountSearchResult resultDto = mapper.convertValue(stringValue, AccountSearchResult.class);
        }, throwable -> {
            //onError
        });
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I would do it the same way too! Thank you!